# Java comparing 2D array to digit is giving exceptions

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to compare a 2D array to a Digit, but its throwing an exception.

Code

```
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;

public class Main {

    public static int[][] map = {{0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1},
    {1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1},
    {2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1},
    {3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1},
    {4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1},
    {5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1},
    {6, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1},
    {7, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5, 1}};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int I = 0;
        int II = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {

            for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++) {

                if (map[x][y] == 0) {
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                    g.fillRect(I, II, 100, 100);
                }
                if (map[x][y] == 1) {
                    g.setColor(Color.orange);
                    g.fillRect(I, II, 100, 100);
                }
                if (map[x][y] == 2) {
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                    g.fillRect(I, II, 100, 100);
                }
                if (map[x][y] == 3) {
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    g.fillRect(I, II, 100, 100);
                }
                if (map[x][y] == 4) {
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                    g.fillRect(I, II, 100, 100);
                }
                if (map[x][y] == 5) {
                    g.setColor(Color.gray);
                    g.fillRect(I, II, 100, 100);
                }
                I = x * 100;
                I = y * 100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception its throwing is `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8`
This is for a bare bones tile map system, if you want to test this you need slick2D and need to put this in the render loop.

Comment: What exception it gives to you?

Comment: What is the definition and purpose of the variable I?

Comment: You should be using `map.length` and `map[x].length` instead of absolute values

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thanks for your inputs everyone, look at the edit.

Comment: @madprogrammer Can you provide an example of using map.lentgh with this?

Comment: `for(int y = 0; y < map.length; y++){` and `for(int x = 0; x < map[x].length; x++){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are trying to access to the row `8` and you only have the maximum of position `7`.

**Remember that the index of rows and columns starts in the position 0 and ends in the length-1.**

**Also, you have to remember that the first position of the array, in your case, `x`, are the rows, and the `y` are the columns.**

```
array[rows][columns]
```

So you have to change the order of your variables in your loops. Like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < map.length; x++){

    for(int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++){
```

The rest of the code can be like you have above.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: It fixes the expection, but I changed map[x][y] == to map[y][x] == but now its not showing the whole array map picture: http://puu.sh/ipdSG/5d124d56d0.png

Comment: @CalebB Why did you change to `map[y][x]`? You only have to replace the code that I put above, I mean, the declaration of the `for loops`, not the content inside of them.

Comment: Its because of how I want the map layed out, but even if I only change the for loop I get this issue, should I open a new question for that issue of now displaying the full map? I prefer not to have to many questions in a short period of time.

Comment: @CalebB Yes, I think you should have to open another question because you are going to ask two issues that are not related and people could get confused. And don't worry about how many questions you have (of course, if you don't spam, they are very poor questions or something like that), the important thing it's that you learn and get your issue solved ;)